# Project Euler 63

Tags: python

The 5-digit number, 16807=75, is also a fifth power. Similarly, the 9-digit number, 134217728=89, is a ninth power.

How many n-digit positive integers exist which are also an nth power?

I have written the following code:

```
ctr=0
for power in range(1,10):
    for base in range (1,10):
        if len(str(base**power))==power:
            lower=base
            break
    if len(str(9**power))==power:
        upper=9
    elif len(str(8**power))==power:
        upper=8
    for k in range(lower,upper+1):
        ctr+=1
print (ctr)
```

But I get 36 as the output as opposed to 49.

The logic works on the following analysis:
1 raised to 1<=x raised to 1<=9 raised to 1
5 raised to 3<=x raised to 3<=9 raised to 3...so on till
9 raised to 9

Which numbers are missing from the count?

Comment: Well, you're missing 75^5 and 89^9 so you know that you should be considering many more bases

Comment: I think it's 7⁵ and not 75⁵. (75⁵ as way more digit than 5.)

Comment: @jaykay What is the use of you 'elif'? + If your logic is good, the last loop should be replaced with ctr+=10-lower

Comment: I can't tell if you are asking for the answer to your homework problem or looking for a bug in your code.

Comment: Ok, your problem is, you use power from 1 to 9. 9^10 for example, is also a 10 digits number. Your problem doesn't come from the base, their is 36 n-digits number that also are a nth-power  < 10. But their is 13 other with power >= 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `for power in range(1,10):` to `for power in range(1,22):`

and you'll have them all. You had the correct thinking about the base, if you get to 10 as a base, the n-th power will never be n-digits. But this isn't correct about the 'n' number. For exemple, 9^21 is 21-digits.

Also I gave you the answer to your question : "which number are missing?" but project Euler is also a mathematical challenge and this is great to learn maths. So you should find a smarter way than the bruteforce I gave you. `1 to 22` works because we already know their is only 49 answer and I bruteforced to get the 49th.

Also, as stated in comments :

```
if len(str(9**power))==power:
    upper=9
elif len(str(8**power))==power:
    upper=8
for k in range(lower,upper+1):
    ctr+=1
```

should be:

```
ctr += 10-lower
```

(Well, even `ctr += 10-base` and remove "lower" var since you break.

Comment: That is what I missed. I'll have to check the math as to why only the range of 1,22 gives the answer.

Comment: As for the latter part of your comment, I feel mine is just an elaborate version of what you suggested. Thanks!